# Maven project does not generate testng results within test-output folder from selenium project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created maven project with selenium and TestNG. When I run the project using pom file it does not generate TestNG results (test-output folder). But when I run the project as testng.xml->(right click) run as -> TestNG suite, it generates the results

Comment: _"When I run the project using pom file"_ how/what exactly are you running?

Comment: Check whether the target folder Or test-output folder is getting generated in your project root directory.

Comment: You will need to provide your POM, the configuration in it will determine where the file should be/why it's not generated.  Using this as an example (https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template) the file would be in `Selenium-Maven-Template/target/failsafe-reports/testng-results.xml` after running a `mvn clean verify`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Run from testNg.xml directly -By default in maven project html reports get created into test-output folder

In case we run from pom.xml using surefire plugin - Reports will get created into target\surefire-reports.

Answer (score 2):

While working with multiple frameworks e.g. *TestNG*, *Maven*, *Gradle* due to synchronization issues within your *IDE* sometimes the **test-output folder** doesn't gets populated with the intended test *results/output* and the *output* tends to remain **buffered**. In these cases once the *Test Execution* gets completed *Refresh* the *Maven Project* and your *test-output folder* would get populated with the intended *results/output*.

Comment: In results/output folder also does not have testng-results.xml

Answer (score 1):

As you are running testng tests from Maven (Surefire), your output folder will be 
`target` instead of `test-output` as defined by the surefire plugin,
so if you are looking for file `testng-results.xml` or any other testng files then check at `\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml`

Comment: Yeah. I have checked this as well. But there is no testng-results.xml in that location as well.

Comment: when u say "When I run the project using pom file", so have you configured your testng.xml in pom? (in surefire plugin), if possible please provide the pom.xml file's surefire snapshot or code